# Partitioning Windows 10 to prevent need for reformatting

Tags: windows-10, partitioning

I know a big issue with Windows is that the majority of people have all of their data on a single partition, which when filled, causes the system to fail since it will no longer be able to boot or execute programs. I have been searching around to find how I should setup my Windows 10 partitions so that this does not happen, but I have not found anything useful.

I would like to know what needs to have its own partition so that it is never possible for me to not be able to boot my machine. I would like it to be so that even if my partition with documents fills up, I am still be able to use computer and free up the space within that partition.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: The premise of the question seems to be this "big issue" which I have never heard of, and which a quick google search doesn't reveal. Could you please provide a link to people mentioning this problem with Windows? Generally, if there is no room on your PC, Windows will not allow you to download any more files, thus a single partition should be sufficient.

Comment: Partitioning a disk when the partitions are being used is slower than one partition. The heads have to move large distances instead of only small distances.

Comment: @Mark Any source to back up this claim? NTFS should spread the data all over the partition rather than write it beginning-to-end, so with one large partition data will be just as spread as with two partition. Also, this is not a problem with SSDs.

Comment: This appears to be an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377) based on a false premise. The actual issue is that *'the majority of people have all of their data'* on a drive that is too small for their needs. The plethora of laptops with 128GB SSDs is the root cause of this. The fix is to buy a bigger drive.

Comment: @gronostaj NTFS does not spread out data.

Comment: @VividKraig Sorry for the confusion on all of this. It is a not exactly a common issue, but it has the off chance of becoming an issue. This is coming from a linux background and I could find the same support when looking up portioning for windows. Here is the [CentOS](https://docs.centos.org/en-US/centos/install-guide/CustomSpoke-x86/#sect-recommended-partitioning-scheme-x86) manual partitioning guide.

Answer (score 0):

It fully depends on you. Ask these questions of yourself to find out how should you partition your HDD:

1. How much is is my HDD capacity?
2. What do I do most in my PC?
3. How do I prefer to organize my data?

For example, I have a 1TB (1000GB) HDD. I'm a developer so I usually use heavy and big programs and have many downloads. I partitioned my HDD like this:

- Windows (C:) => 125 GB: Windows 10 and some of my programs
- Apps (D:) => 300 GB: Bigger apps like Visual Studio, Android Studio, etc.
- Games and Files (E:) => 300 GB: Games and personal files
- Downloads (F:) => 100 GB: Only for downloads
- Others (G:) => 75 GB: Other files like Virtual Machine files
- Three other partitions (15, 10, 8 GB) for my Linux (Linux Mint OS)
- Some small partitions for EFI, Recovery, etc. (created by system automatically)

Comment: Why do you have D, E, F, G as separate volumes instead of a single one?

Comment: @gronostaj Because of my answer to 3rd question. I preferred this way because less files in a partition means easier management.